# Android Chrome goes back to redirect chain origin after deeplink is triggered

Tags: php, android, google-chrome-app, deep-linking

I am writing a little webapp that does the following:

1. Show a form to the user.
2. On submit, a PHP file is called. This performs a redirect to a static html page.
3. The page attempts to open a deeplink for an Android app (e.g. the play store).

Everything works fine on all mobile OSs and browsers, apart from Chrome on Android. In this case, after opening the deeplink, something in the browser calls the url at point 1, thus going back to the initial page. This is inconvenient for my webapp, because in the real use case page 3 contains more logic that is unfortunately not executed.

Does anyone have any clue about what is going on? Below you can find a very basic version of what I need to do, as even in this case the issue occurs I really don't know where to look :/

Thank you in advance for all!

page-one.html

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="page-two.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Click here" />
</form>
</html>
```

page-two.php

```
<?php
header('Location: page-three.html');
```

page-three.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            window.location = "market://details?id=com.android.chrome";
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
As suggested on the Google Chrome Help Forum I already tried the following:

1. Clear your App's Cache and Data: Open Phone settings> Select Apps > Click Chrome > Click CLEAR DATA > Click CLEAR CACHE.
2. If the issue still persists, uninstall and reinstall Chrome.
3. Also, try the Chrome Beta & Chrome Canary and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: why you call page 3. you can use You link in page 2 ?

Comment: This is a simplification of the real-life case, where `page-three` is a more complex webapp. I stripped all the extra logic to make sure that the issue was not occurring because of my code, but I keep getting it even in this basic setup